# Basic looping login menu

Tags: c#, loops

I'm trying to make my login system reject a blank space. I've used a while loop to try and make it loop back but it wont work. Ive currently made it only 0-9 is accepted, but would rather any numbers are accepted and just blank spaces are looped back to login again after a message box. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
namespace OrderingSystem
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "1")
            { 
                    lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text; 
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "2")
            {
                    lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        

        private void lblPin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "3")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "4")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "5")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "6")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "7")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "8")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "9")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button num = (Button)sender;
            if (num.Text == "0")
            {
                lblPin.Text = lblPin.Text + num.Text;
            }
        }

        public static string server = "";

        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool IncorrectPin = true;
            while (IncorrectPin)
            {
                if (lblPin.Text == "1")
                {
                    server = "Oli";
                    IncorrectPin = false;
                }
                else if (lblPin.Text == "0")
                {
                    server = "Training";
                    IncorrectPin = false;

                }
                else if (lblPin.Text == "2" + "3" + "4" + "5" + "6" + "7" + "8" + "9")
                {
                    server = "Please Login";
                    IncorrectPin = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a pin 0-9");
                } 
            }
            
            this.Hide();
            TillView sistema = new TillView();
            sistema.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();


        }



        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What aren't you using the same event handler for all buttons?

Comment: @McNets how would i do that? apologies new to programming

Comment: `else if (lblPin.Text == "2" + "3" + "4" + "5" + "6" + "7" + "8" + "9")` This doesn't do what you think it is.  It's not checking for any of those individual numbers, it's looking for the exact string "23456789".  You need multiple conditions here.  If keeping this design, might be easier with a switch statement and multiple cases that fall through to the same behavior.

Comment: I answered, but don't see any need for looping here.  If my answer doesn't work please clarify the question.  You're accessing GUI elements in the loop so don't see how those values ever change while looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't perfect by any means, but should get the behavior you want.  Don't see any need for a loop.

Per your comment

> but would rather any numbers are accepted

I do no tests against `numberEntered`.  But you could check that against a range if you wanted.

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberEntered = -1;
    //Presuming you only want integers
    //This returns false if we can't convert the text to an int
    if (!int.TryParse(lblPin.Text, out numberEntered))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a pin using numbers only, no spaces");
        return;
    }
    if (numberEntered == 1)
    {
        server = "Oli";
    }
    else if (numberEntered == 0)
    {
        server = "Training";
    }
    else
    {
        server = "Please Login";
    }

    this.Hide();
    TillView sistema = new TillView();
    sistema.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```